# Authorization response of TIdHTTP->Connect() to get session ID

Tags: c++builder, indy10, idhttp, rad-studio

I am using the `TIdHTTP` component to connect to my server. I am using the following code for that (this is not complete code, I have removed unnecessary code lines). With the below code, I can connect to the server, and I can send a `GET` request to it.

My query is while authorization (in the `Connect` call), server sends a sessionID, which is required while making a `GET` request. How can I get that sessionID once the `http->Connect()` call is successful?

If I use a `GET` request for authorization, then I get the session ID using a Cookie manager. But I am interested if I can get that using a `Connect()` call.

```
 TIdHTTP* http = new TIdHTTP();
 /// Code to set IO handler and setting custom headers
 http->Connect(ipAddress,port);

 if(http->Connected())
 {
    http->Get(url,memStream);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is - NO, you cannot get a session ID from `Connect()`, because getting a session ID requires you to first make an HTTP request so the server can send a response, and `Connect()` does not send any request, it merely opens the underlying socket connection to the server's listening port. The actual request is not sent until you call the `TIdHTTP::Get()` method (or any other request method - `Post()`, `Put()`, `Delete()`, etc).

Besides, you are not supposed to be calling the `TIdHTTP::Connect()` method *manually* **at all**. HTTP is a stateless protocol, there is no guarantee (or need) for a TCP connection to be persisted between multiple requests to the same server. That is negotiated between client and server on a per-request basis, and `TIdHTTP` handles that internally, (re)connecting as needed for each request sent.  All you need to do is supply a URL to `Get()` (or whichever request you need), and then `TIdHTTP` parses it to extract the host:port information and manage the socket connection accordingly.

If the server requires HTTP-level authentication (as opposed to webform-based authentication), it will ask for that in a response, which `TIdHTTP` handles if you have the `hoProcessAuth` flag enabled in the `TOdHTTP::HTTPOptions` property, thus triggering the `TIdHTTP::On(Select)Authorization` events as needed, so it can then retry the request with the authentication info added. There are also `Username` and `Password` subproperties available in the `TIdHTTP::Request` property.